# Data posting isn't working in PHP Curl

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm trying to make a script that makes things easier for Apple users, I don't really want to expose it right now but those are the steps I need to follow.

1. Login to Apple and saving the cookies.
2. Getting the data from apple with the saved cookies.
3. Creating automation tools.

And i'm stuck in the first step, Curl isn't submitting the custom headers as I need to submit the json header.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
function login($url,$data){
    $data=json_encode($data);
    $login = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data))                                                                       
);     
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    //ob_start();
    $rez=curl_exec ($login);  
}                   

$data = array("accountName" => "myemail@me.com", "password" => "MyPassWord","rememberMe" => "true"); 
$url="https://idmsa.apple.com/appleauth/auth/signin";    
login($url,$data);
?>
```

**Whenever I try tampering the data when sending request, it never shows the custom headers**

Comment: How do you check for the presence of the headers? (how do you know they're not being sent)

Comment: What I mean is: Your code initiates a request that goes from your server to Apple right? So how can the browser see the traffic between your server and Apple server? The info you get from the browser is about the traffic between the browser and your server. `GET` is the method the browser used to retrieve the page from your server, not necessarily the method cURL uses to call Apple. This is why I ask how can you tell what headers are sent by cURL

Comment: But i tried this in the PAST , it was all going well and headers are being sent as it was supposed to , now i don't even see posted values as json data , i find everything empty. Idk what i've done wrong this time.

Answer (score 0):

This would be unmanageable as a comment, so here is how i `see` what goes on the wire:

```
        $verbiage = null;
        if ($this->verbose) {
            curl_setopt($ch , CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT , false);
            curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_VERBOSE , true);
            $verbiage = fopen('php://temp' , 'w+');
            curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_STDERR , $verbiage);
        }

        $resp = curl_exec($ch);

        if ($this->verbose) {
            rewind($verbiage);
            $verboseLog = stream_get_contents($verbiage);
            $log->info("Verbose information:\n$verboseLog");
            fclose($verbiage);
        }


        curl_close($ch);
```

where $log is a log4php object, you pick your display method.

**EDIT** adding a sample log with this 'trace' option enabled

```
INFO - testCreateLabRequest starts.
TRACE - Query for lab request [dispensary[1]inboundLabRequest[2]ForPatient[1]] returned no records for feed [toubibCreamedFeedGuid]
DEBUG - Sending json 
{ *redacted* , "trackingId":"5ac4473b-407f-4d7d-83eb-1a3f9abe5b8b"}

INFO - Verbose information:
*   Trying fe80::3636:3bff:fecf:804c...
* Connected to darkmax.local (fe80::3636:3bff:fecf:804c) port 80 (#0)
> POST /ehr/feed/lab/request HTTP/1.1
Host: darkmax.local
Protocol_version : 1.1
Connection: Close
Content-Type: application/json ; charset=utf-8
Proxy-Connection: Close
User-Agent: Portable EHR(106)
Accept: application/json, text/html;
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Content-Length: 851

* upload completely sent off: 851 out of 851 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 31 Aug 2016 02:04:03 GMT
< Server: Apachee/2.4.12
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Origin: http://darkmax.local
< Connection: close
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: application/json;  charset=utf-8
< 
* Closing connection 0
```

The lines with a `<` correspond to what my cURL session is receiving from the remote peer. Having some visibility into the actual HTTP protocol flying from me-to-peer-back-to-me has helped me many times figure out the nature of some underlying issue.

Comment: Can you please explain to me what this is supposed to do exactly ?

Comment: I was trying to give you options, maybe i misunderstood your question. This will provide you some detail about the connection status with the peer (apple), specifically what is travelint to-from the remote.  I added an example using this. I hoped you could find a hint in there as to the nature of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Apple uses `X-Apple-Widget-Key` like `CSRF`. I think you need to catch it. You can find it on `source code`. You can get status by using `curl_getinfo()`

[image]
    // your code .....

```
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
//ob_start();
$rez = curl_exec($login);
$status = curl_getinfo($login);

print_r($status);
```

Comment: @Yak, please change `curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);` to true. By `curl_getinfo` you has to receive returned headers not options.

Comment: `Array ( [url] => https://idmsa.apple.com/appleauth/auth/signin [content_type] => text/html;charset=UTF-8 [http_code] => 200 [header_size] => 1558 [request_size] => 303 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.919805 [namelookup_time] => 0.060495 [connect_time] => 0.214772 [pretransfer_time] => 0.55338 [size_upload] => 76 [size_download] => 20911 [speed_download] => 22734 [speed_upload] => 82 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => 76 [starttransfer_time] => 0.769499 [redirect_time] => 0 [redirect_url] =>`

Comment: `[primary_ip] => 17.171.11.86 [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_port] => 443 [local_ip] => 192.168.1.68 [local_port] => 48558 )`

Comment: So this is what it returns